# Extracting all sub-tags' values in a main tag for XML File no matter the tag name

Tags: python, xml, getelementsbytagname, minidom

```
<GPO>
    <Computer>
        <ExtensionData>
            <Extension xmlns:q1="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Security" 
             xsi:type="q1:SecuritySettings">
                <q1:Account>
                    <q1:Name>ClearTextPassword</q1:Name>
                    <q1:SettingBoolean>false</q1:SettingBoolean>
                    <q1:Type>Password</q1:Type>
                </q1:Account>

               <q1:Account>
                   <q1:Name>MaximumPasswordAge</q1:Name>
                  <q1:SettingNumber>120</q1:SettingNumber>
                  <q1:Type>Password</q1:Type>
               </q1:Account>
             </Extension>
       </ExtensionData>
    </Computer>
</GPO>
```

Hi, this is my current XML file saved into C:\XMLFile.xml. How can I change the code to extract all the sub-tags' values inside each <q1:Account> tag using Python 3.8 instead of just by tag name? I have no experience towards XML parsing and reading with Python before.

This is my code so far:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmlFile = minidom.parse("C:\GPOReportAD.xml")

computer = xmlFile.getElementsByTagName("Computer")[0]

extensionData = computer.getElementsByTagName("ExtensionData")[0]

for i in extensionData.getElementsByTagName("q1:Name"):
  for x in extensionData.getElementsByTagName("q1:SettingBoolean"):
    print("Result: " + i.firstChild.data + " " + x.firstChild.data)
    break
```

Expected Output:

```
ClearTextPassword    false
MaxmimumPasswordAge  120
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the exact expected output? Also, can you use a library like lxml?

Comment: Xpath is better for querying XML.

Comment: Should I use etree from lxml package or Xpath? I have 0 experience with retrieving values with XML at all, which is easier to understand for a rookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with an xml snippet which uses namespaces, making things a bit complicated. Best way to approach it, I believe, is to use the html (not xml) parser from lxml and use xpath to select the values:

```
import lxml.html as lh
gpo = """[your snippet above]"""

doc = lh.fromstring(gpo)
#either:
for i in doc.xpath(".//*[local-name()='name']"):
#or
for i in doc.xpath(".//name", namespaces={'ql':'http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Security'}):
    print(i.text,i.xpath('./following-sibling::*[1]/text()')[0])
```

Output:

```
ClearTextPassword false
MaximumPasswordAge 120
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask another question? Say the snippet above is derived from a file, how can I put it inside the """ and """ which is assigned to the gpo variable?

Comment: Also, does ".//*[local-name()='name']" refer to the tag "q1:Name"?

Comment: @Xteriz To the first question: no, you'll have to parse the file; something like: `tree = lh.parse('myfile.xml')  doc =tree.getroot()`. To the 2nd question: yes. You'll have to do some research to really understand these.

Comment: Will do. Thank you so much!